# Visual indication of network activity

Tags: windows, networking

is there a simple application which can sit on top of a fullscreen game to give me an indicator of when there is a lot of network activity? I can only seem to find system tray apps or programs which work outside of fullscreen games. Preferably something transparent so i can see through it.

A little background info: I used to have my PC sitting sideways on my desk so I can see lights from the network card. The lights stopped working a while ago and all I need is a little blinking application to tell me when there is activity. I do not need a detailed graph or bandwidth usage, just activity notification. I've looked everywhere for something, maybe you guys are better at searching than me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe this nifty little app will come in handy:

[Network Lights](http://www.itsamples.com/network-lights.html)

> Network Lights is a Windows program,
>   which blinks keyboard LEDs (Light
>   Emitting Diode) indicating outgoing
>   and incoming network packets on
>   network interface.
>
> Network Lights lets you monitor
>   network activity (upload/download)
>   from your keyboard ScrollLock and
>   NumLock indicators. Each LED will
>   flicker when network traffic is
>   detected.
>
> This utility is a standalone
>   executable. Run the program, you'll
>   see a new system tray icon. Now you
>   can monitor your network traffic using
>   the ScrollLock and NumLock leds on
>   your keyboard. Use the system tray
>   icon (click the mouse) to customize
>   program settings.

[image]

Network Lights is free, open source, and portable.

Comment: HA! that's cute :)

Comment: this looks nice. i dont use those anyways.

Answer (score 0):

you can force pretty much any application (and indeed a network traffic monitor) to be always on top (e.g. with a window manager, most of them can also make the window transparent, check Eusing's [Auto Window Manager](http://www.eusing.com/WindowManager/WindowManager.htm), it's free), however, most likely they will be knocked off by a fullscreen game.

which game btw?

Comment: it will be used with multiple games.

Answer (score 0):

The Logitech G15 keyboard is great for this. It can run all sorts of little programs in its LCD monitor. I use mine mostly to look at CPU and RAM usage (and to get IM notifications).
It's a bit pricey, but it's a great keyboard overall (subjective).

See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logitech_G15

Comment: Yea, I love the G15.  Now if only they made it with the curved ergonomic design that I like on my work computer...

Comment: looks nice but i cant really afford that right now

Comment: Yup, they should lower the price on it, it's really expensive... that's the biggest problem with the G15 IMHO. One can buy a full computer for the price of 3 or 4 of these keyboards nowadays... doesn't make much sense pricewise indeed. But if you can afford it, it proves quite useful at times.